# GCC - Member should be initialized in member initialization list

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, warnings, member

I keep getting this warning with GCC, but I didn't enable it in any way for this project. I tried creating a new project (I'm running the Code::Blocks IDE in Ubuntu), and I'm still getting the warning. Help, please?

Edit: Invoking GCC manually does not cause this issue, but invoking it through Code::Blocks (with all warnings disabled) does cause it. From this, I'm guessing it's a Code::Blocks bug.

Edit2: Fixed. Turns out Code::Blocks has global compiler flags which can't be overridden inside specific projects, and this was causing the error.

Comment: Please post the snippet of code that GCC is flagging, and the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Then do what the warning tells you to do. Most likely it is there with a reason.

You can always ignore warnings. Also, you are most likely passing a parameter to the gcc that enables that warning.